# Ionic 2 responsive grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I make a responsive grid in Ionic 2? Ionic 1 supported reserved classes like `responsive-md` or `responsive-sm` that made grids responsive, but they don't seem to work in Ionic 2.

In my case I have an `<ion-row>` with three `<ion-col>`. I would like the columns to drop below each other when the display width drops below a threshold. Is it possible to do this with Ionic 2?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Though it does not seem to appear in the Ionic 2 documentation currently, the `responsive-md`, `responsive-sm` (etc.) classes in Ionic 1 now become individual attributes in Ionic 2.

Here is an example:

```
  <ion-row responsive-sm>
    <ion-col width-10>This column will take 10% of space</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: I hope it this answer is still valid. I can't find it anywhere in the source

Comment: Ionic has updated their responsive ion-grid. The attributes have all changed to be more like Bootstrap. http://blog.ionic.io/build-awesome-desktop-apps-with-ionics-new-responsive-grid/

Answer (score 1):

Now Ionic is using [Bootstrap grid system](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#customizing-the-grid). We can also use **fixed** attribute on ion-grid to better utilize screen width.

I tried by using following code for my requirements. Please follow the comments for understanding.

We can override the breakpoints so I did this:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  sm: 0,
  ssm: 320px, // second small breakpoint
  tsm: 372px, // third small breakpoint. This is the threshold for high resolution devices. 
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);

$grid-max-widths: (
  sm: 292px,
  ssm: 100%,
  tsm: 100%,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px
);
```

and here is the code using customised breakpoint:

```
 <ion-grid fixed>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-2 col-tsm-2>
          1 of 3
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-10 col-tsm-6>
          2 of 3
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4 push-2 push-tsm-0 col-tsm-4> // pushing 2 columns at the beginning for low resolution devices
          3 of 3
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

You would get following output for low resolution devices i.e devices that are below min-width: 372px;

[image]

And following output for above devices:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Update for Ionic 2, Ionic 3+:

Ionic now have an amazing grid system base on [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) css. You can see in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/).
To use it, just simple like that:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-3></ion-col> //This col will take 3/12 = 25% width;
    <ion-col col-4></ion-col> //This col will take 4/12 = 33.33% width;
    <ion-col></ion-col>       //This col will take the rest of width;
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```