# How to get a responsive grid layout in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, responsive-design, flexbox, ionic2

It is very unclear how to create a responsive layout grid in Ionic 2. I hope someone can shed some light onto this topic.

I got a [grid](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid):

```html
<ion-content class="home card-background-page" padding>
  <ion-row wrap>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let location of dataService.allLocationDetail.location | keys" (click)="openPage(location.data.locationId)">
        <img [src]="location.data.coverArt"/>
        <div class="card-title">{{location.data.name}}</div>
        <div class="card-subtitle">{{location.data.date}}</div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

I want the ion-col as a max-width of, let say 500px. Then if the view is larger than 500px like in a iPad landscape, I want the col wrap - 2 col in a row and they are center aligned. I added the wrap attribute on to the row and it does not seem to works.

Also, is there responsive grid in Ionic2? If so, how can I use it? I also want the ion-content has a max-width and will align center when the screen width is larger than the max-width. Right now, the ion-content is position absolute and won't allow center.

What is the best strategy to dong responsive layout with Ionic 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Hugh Hou: I found a good interesting answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018146/ionic-2-responsive-grid). Seem ionic 2 missing some documentation regarding responsive grid.

You should also refer to this following link for ionic 1 responsive grid. [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-responsive)

So in conclusion, to archive your goal.

1. In mobile device show every col as full-width.
2. In tablet device show 2 or more col in a row.

Try to do so

```
<ion-content class="home card-background-page" padding>
  <ion-row responsive-sm>      
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let location of dataService.allLocationDetail.location | keys" (click)="openPage(location.data.locationId)">
        <img [src]="location.data.coverArt"/>
        <div class="card-title">{{location.data.name}}</div>
        <div class="card-subtitle">{{location.data.date}}</div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Now Ionic is using [Bootstrap grid system](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#customizing-the-grid). We can easily do this using **fixed** attribute on ion-grid.