# How to have a responsive ionic grid in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, responsive-design, ionic2

I have a list of cards that I need to show them in 1 column in small devices and 2 columns in medium device and 3 columns in large devices

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432126/2279488 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432126/2279488 I tried below codes but no success at the end.

1.

```
 <ion-row  responsive-sm>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let card of cards" width-50>
      <ion-card >
```

on small device it shows correctly, on large and medium it shows 2 cards only

2.

```
  <ion-row  responsive-sm>
    <ion-col  width-50>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let card of cards">
```

on small device it shows correctly, on large and medium 1 column is shown and all cards are in the column

3.

```
  <ion-row  responsive-sm>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let card of cards">
```

on small device it shows correctly, on medium and large it shows only 1 column and cards are shown in that column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in case other people having same issue

I added wrap to my first code and it works.

```
  <ion-row  responsive-sm wrap>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let card of cards" width-50>
      <ion-card >
```

Answer (score 0):

I added in my HTML below code and it working for me.

```
 <ion-row class="categoryView">
        <ion-col class="gridCol" width-40></ion-col>
        <ion-col class="gridCol" width-40></ion-col>
      </ion-row>

ion-col.gridCol.col {
      height: 80px;
      background: azure;
      margin: 10px;
  }

  ion-row.categoryView.row {
      height: 100px;
      background: black;
  }
```